# How to connect to a room with a Socket.IO client on Android?

Tags: android, socket.io

I am using the [android-websockets](https://github.com/koush/android-websockets) library to connect to our Socket.IO server. The connection is created, but I can't connect to a room.

In javascript, our code looks like this:

```
emit('subscribe', { 'channel' : 'test' });
```

I've tried using `client.of("test", callback)`, `client.emit("subscribe", jsonArray)` where the array has the channel, but I always end up with a `Creating frame error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io servers require authentication. This is done by sending a post to /socket.io/1/ at the server and reading the response which will look like this:

```
srGlg8x2YschJzuGVeeq:60:60:websocket,htmlfile,xhr-polling,jsonp-polling
```

The string before the first ":" is the key.
Now if you are connecting to the server via a websocket the address will be:

```
ws://(Your socket.io server)/socket.io/1/websocket/(The key)
```

More information on the socket.io protocol: github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec

ps. I don't know anything about android programming but I'm just explaining the socket.io protocol